# Error: INT is incompatible with DATE while passing date argument

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting below error while passing date as parameter to stored procedure

Operand type clash: INT is incompatible with DATE

Tried with 2017-04-03 and '2017-04-03'.Still not working

Example: 
exec > 20160403

Procedure defined as :

---

@stlddate date
...
...

Please help to resolve it.

Comment: In case you're inserting the string directly into the query, the SQL-compliant syntax is `DATE '2017-04-03'`. But I would strongly suggest you use whatever prepared statement API is available in the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Get store procedure parameter as INT and then convert into date datatype :

```
 DECLARE @date INT;
 SET @date = 20170403    
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), @date),  
 112),110)as datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `20160403` looks like an integer. You could try either:

```
'2016-04-03'
```

or

```
cast('20160403' as date)
```

Without more information it is impossible to check this myself.

Comment: I have defined the date value is INT in procedure and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippets.

```
SELECT cast(CONVERT(char(10), 20160403, 126) as DATE)

SELECT cast(CONVERT(char(10), '20160403', 126) as DATE)
```

or

```
DECLARE @DATE INT = 20160403
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CAST(@DATE as VARCHAR), 101)
```

Above three snippets will give the output as 2016-04-03.

[image: Output]